# Laravel Eloquent Inaccessible by $model->id;

Tags: php, mysql, oop, laravel, eloquent

I've done this many times before but somehow my mind is stuck on this one:

```
$data['conversations'] = Conversation::with("sender")->received()->get();
```

Doing `{{ $conversation }}` produces:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "subject": "",
    "sender": {
        "id": "4",
        "email": "jane@doe.com",
        "name": "Jane Poe",
        "group_id": "3",
        "created_at": "2014-12-22 20:31:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-12-22 20:31:00"
    },
    "receiver": "1",
    "created_at": "2015-01-04 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "2015-01-04 00:00:00"
}
```

Notice that "sender? Now `{{ $conversation->sender->email }}` gives:

> Trying to get property of non-object

When calling `{{ $conversation->sender }}` it prints "4" only (the id).

sender is stored in *conversation* table in a column named *sender*.

`$conversation->sender()`  didn't work either

This is the code:

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'conversations';

    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','sender','id');
    }

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','receiver','id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The relation can't have the same name as the foreign key** (or basically any column)

Just change `sender` to `sender_id`. Then you can even remove it from the relationship declaration since it's the conventional naming.

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

(And because `id` is probably the primary key of `User` you can remove that as well)